# Dealing with inverse trig functions in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data set with about 1 billion rows and I am trying to run a procedure where I calculate the distances between many points on a sphere contained in the data set.  I believe that because I am using many trig functions in the calculations (including nested trig functions and inverse trig functions) the code is ridiculously slow.

It only took me ~ 5 minutes to create the table with a cross join, but it is over two hours to complete these calculations in a data set.  Is there some functionality to speed up these trig functions (ie reduce the accuracy in exchange for speed?)

edit:
My stats (on a smaller data set) are:
real time           37:57.86
user cpu time       20:56.32
system cpu time     1:01.37

I am a bit surprised that all the work seems to be done on the user cpu even though I am using a remote submit.  Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Are your points latitude and longitude co-ordinates, and if so, have you tried using the `geodist` function?

Comment: Also, to what end are you calculating so many distances? If you're trying to find nearest neighbours, there may be other ways of improving performance.

Comment: I do make use of `geodist` where I can, however I also need to calculate spherical bearings and I don't think there is a better way to do this other than using lots of trig functions.

Comment: Please post some sample data (or code to generate a dataset) and the code you're currently using, and perhaps people will be able to make some suggestions.